# Green Button energy data

Tags: data-request, usa, time-series, energy

The [Green Button Data](http://greenbuttondata.org/) program in the US allows energy consumers to easily download their consumption data in a [standard XML format](https://github.com/energyos/OpenESPI-Common-java/blob/master/etc/espiDerived.xsd). With that exported file, they can upload to a 3rd party [site or app](http://en.openei.org/apps/?keyword=Green%20Button%20Apps), who will provide a customized report.

[image]

---

My question: **Are there any public data sets of real consumer green button data? For example, home-efficiency enthusiasts who have made their data public, either alone or as a group?**

(I'll self-answer with some better know sample data sources)

[image: green button map]

---

Related question:

[Is there a list of all utilities that offer the Green Button Download and Green Button Connect?](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/6/1511)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some better known **sample** data sets

- [Electricity usage data](http://energy.gov/downloads/green-button-sample-data-pge) that reflect different usage patterns common among PG&E customers
- [Department of Energy Data](http://services.greenbuttondata.org/sample-data.html) by Design Challenge sample data
- [Green Button sample from Texas](http://energy.gov/downloads/green-button-sample-texas) - two households
- [OpenEI Energy Datasets](http://en.openei.org/wiki/Green_Button_Developer#OpenEI_Energy_Datasets) (I can't quickly find any Green Button formats)
- [SDGE (San Diego Gas & Electric) Electric Interval Data](http://www.sdge.com/documents/green-button-60-min-meter-interval-sample-data-csv) Feb 1 2011 to Feb 1 2012 (CSV?)
- [NIST Software Development Kit](https://collaborate.nist.gov/twiki-sggrid/bin/view/SmartGrid/GreenButtonSDK) - seems to be only simulated time series
- [Ontario Green Button Sample Datasets](https://web.archive.org/web/20141117022242/http://greenbuttondata.ca/resources/) - Six total, including hourly, daily, and monthly datasets.

[image]

([my source](http://www.thetrainingset.com/articles/Feeding-The-Data-Monster/) for some links)

Comment: there's at least one (maybe more, not 100%) on canada's green button site via wayback https://web.archive.org/web/20141117022242/http://greenbuttondata.ca/resources/

Comment: @albert can you post as an answer? or should I make this answer a community wiki?

Comment: i think your answer is sufficient